# How to parse a url from a string in xml

Tags: php, parsing

Hello I want to parse(get) only url from this string. How can I achieve this?

```
$string = "<reference name="head"> <action method="addLinkRel"> <rel>canonical</rel> <href>**url**</href> </action> </reference>";
```

Comment: Kindly post your code then only we can help you.

Comment: No code is needed in this situation. I just want to get url onlz from a string.

Comment: How do you intend to parse it without any code then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regexp. E.g.

```
/<href>(.*)<\/href>/
```